# Hide char array from reverse engineer

Tags: c++, string, encryption, character-encoding, hide

Looking for the easiest way to hide `char*` from reverse engineer. Doesn't have to be strong encryption, but something simple. It has to happen in header, and here is my code:

```
#pragma once
const char * pw = "test";
#define PASS pw;
```

where `PASS` is used in the source.

I already tried reverse string and hex to text and vice versa but didn't succeed. Someone please post some easy solution for this.

**Edit:** This is just an example. The user will not input anything, I only have to hide a char pointer from debugger. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Plenty of ways you can do this, there are too many answers to be able to have one correct method. One simple method is to set `pw = "uftu";` and when the user provides something, just add 1 to each of their characters. The answer from @MikeMB regarding hashes is a much better way to solve the problem though.

Comment: Edited the post - there isn't any kind of user inputs. :) This just have to be hidden from the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way would be to store only the hash of your string (computed offline and outside the code) in the code and to hash any user input with which you want to compare it during runtime and then compare the hashes instead of the plain passwords

Answer (score 0):

You could store the XOR value of the password, and then XOR the user input to compare. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572463/1760335) for the code.

Then the problem becomes someone can run a debugger or dis-assembler to reveal what your program is doing when it checks the password.